# The speed of runnig of my application on emulator with Intellij is very slow

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I try to run my application on my emulator with IntelliJ Idea it takes something about 10 minutes and it shows me below phrases during these minutes:

> Waiting for device. Target device: Android_em [emulator-5554]
>   Uploading file    local path:
>   C:\Users\elyas\Desktop\Practice1\out\production\Practice1\Practice1.apk
>     remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.Practice1

What should I do right now? it's very disturbing !
The version of my IntelliJ is :

> 13.1.3

Comment: I use Eclipse and running on the emulator is just as slow, especially when you run it for the first time. Its quicker to debug on a device connected via usb.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, but I have Windows Phone mobile phone :D so I don't have a android based mobile phone, any way thank you for suggestion !

Comment: You'll definitely have to debug/test on an actual device to check rotation issues, network connectivity etc. Or borrow someones :-)

Comment: Are you using the **ARM-based** or the **x68**-based emulators? The ARM-based emulators are real slow, but ever since Google/Intel started providing x86-based emulators, I've had no problems with poor emulator performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the answer but you can try genymotion, it's very fast, Android Emulator is slow!
http://www.genymotion.com

Comment: Is it possible to bundle it to IntelliJ? I mean instead of using SDK AVD can I say to IntelliJ to run application by Genymotion Emulator?

Comment: Yes, you only must run an Genymotion Emulator and IntelliJ will show it in "Choose Device" dialog. With Genymotion you can run in much more devices, fast and easily. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and respond, It's very stable and good emulator, I have never experienced my application in this speed

don't care about English, you speak understandable. In addition I am not a native English speaker ! ;-)